# How match data in R based on specific variable

Tags: r, match

I have a sample file with 2 percent of the total population(1.5 million samples from 75 million total population) extracted from the census of Iran in 2016. Following I bring 22 individuals as an example:

```
sample <- structure(list(household.ID = c(16523634, 16523634, 16523634, 16523634,16525912, 
    16525912, 16540127,16540127, 16598050, 16598050, 16611764,16611764, 16611764, 16643309, 
    16643309, 16652356, 16652356,16652356, 16672105, 16672105, 16672105,16672105
    ),Member.ID= c(16527193, 16529443, 16532250, 16534992,16527527, 16529230, 
    16542499,16545263, 16616975, 16620223, 16633984,16642611, 16650837, 16646986, 16650210, 
    16660335, 16665128,16668381, 16676674, 16681528, 16685073,16687491
    ),Relatshinship= c(1,2,3,3,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,3),birth.year= 
    c(1346,1348,1376,1377,1357,1367,1316,1319,1329,1374,1339,1342,1367,1343,1336 ,1321 
     ,1326,1367,1338,1352,1372,1381),Gender  = c(1,2 ,1,2,1,2,1 ,2,1 ,1,1 ,2,1 ,1 ,2 ,1,2 ,2,1 
     ,2,1,1),age    = c(49,47,19 ,18,38,28,78,75,66 ,21,56 ,52 ,28,51 ,58 ,74 ,68 ,27  ,56 
    ,43,23 ,13),marriage.stuatus= c(1,1 ,4 ,4 ,1,1,1,1,2,4,1,1 ,1,1 ,1,1,1 ,4,1 ,1,4 ,4),   
    number.of.children.ever.born= c(NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,3,NA,3,NA,NA,2,NA,NA),    
    number.of.living.children  = c(NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,3,NA,3,NA,NA,2,NA, NA)), 
    row.names = c(NA, -22L),class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a birth history for women. For doing this, I need to match children to their mothers. I have a column in my data in which an individual’s relationship with the head of the household is mentioned. Code 1 is the head of household, 2 is the wife of the head and 3 refers to children, 4 to son-in-law or daughter in low, 5 to Grandchild, 6 to father or mother and etc. For instance, in my data, the first household (ID: 16523634) has 4 members, which comprised of the head of the family which is here a man (code: 1= man, 2= women), his wife, and two children which are a son (age: 19) and a daughter(age:18). Long story short, I need to match children-who also present in data- to their mother in the household, in a way that I can have column for each mother in which the age of each children matched be specified in the column. I wish my data finally culminate into something like this:

| H.ID | M.ID | B.year | Gender | age | First child | second child | Third child |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16523634 | 16529443 | 1348 | 2 | 47 | 19 | 18 | NA |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Starting Data

When I loaded `sample` from the OP, there were two vectors in the dataframe that were only length == 21, so I added some `NA` just to get a valid starting point. Here's what I used:

```
library(tidyverse)

sample <-
  tibble(
    household.ID = c(
      16523634,16523634,16523634,16523634,16525912,16525912,
      16540127,16540127,16598050,16598050,16611764,16611764,
      16611764,16643309,16643309,16652356,16652356,16652356,
      16672105,16672105,16672105,16672105),
    Member.ID= c(16527193, 16529443, 16532250, 16534992,16527527, 16529230, 
                 16542499,16545263, 16616975, 16620223, 16633984,16642611, 
                 16650837, 16646986, 16650210, 16660335, 16665128,16668381, 
                 16676674, 16681528, 16685073,16687491),
    Relatshinship = c(1,2,3,3,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,3),
    birth.year = c(1346,1348,1376,1377,1357,1367,1316,1319,1329,1374,1339,
                   1342,1367,1343,1336 ,1321,1326,1367,1338,1352,1372,1381),
    Gender = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1),
    age = c(49,47,19,18,38,28,78,75,66,21,56,52,28,51,58,74,68,27,56,43,23,13),
  marriage.stuatus= c(1,1,4,4,1,1,1,1,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,1,1,4,4),
  number.of.children.ever.born= c(NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,
                                  3,NA,3,NA,NA,2,NA,NA),    
  number.of.living.children  = c(NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,
                                 3,NA,3,NA,NA,2,NA,NA))
```

Seems cruel, but let's start by separating mothers and children from their families:

```
df_mothers <- sample %>% 
  filter(Relatshinship == 2) %>% 
  print()

# A tibble: 7 × 9
  household.ID Member.ID Relatshinship birth.year Gender   age marriage.stuatus number.of.children.ever.born number.of.living.children
         <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>                        <dbl>                     <dbl>
1     16523634  16529443             2       1348      2    47                1                            2                         2
2     16525912  16529230             2       1367      2    28                1                           NA                        NA
3     16540127  16545263             2       1319      2    75                1                            6                         4
4     16611764  16642611             2       1342      2    52                1                            2                         2
5     16643309  16650210             2       1336      2    58                1                            3                         3
6     16652356  16665128             2       1326      2    68                1                            3                         3
7     16672105  16681528             2       1352      2    43                1                            2                         2

df_children <- sample %>% 
  filter(Relatshinship == 3) %>% 
  group_by(household.ID) %>% 
  arrange(household.ID,desc(age)) %>% 
  mutate(birth.order = ordinal(row_number())) %>% 
  select(-c(marriage.stuatus, number.of.children.ever.born, number.of.living.children)) %>%
  print()

# A tibble: 7 × 7
# Groups:   household.ID [5]
  household.ID Member.ID Relatshinship birth.year Gender   age birth.order
         <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
1     16523634  16532250             3       1376      1    19 1st        
2     16523634  16534992             3       1377      2    18 2nd        
3     16598050  16620223             3       1374      1    21 1st        
4     16611764  16650837             3       1367      1    28 1st        
5     16652356  16668381             3       1367      2    27 1st        
6     16672105  16685073             3       1372      1    23 1st        
7     16672105  16687491             3       1381      1    13 2nd
```

Okay, that gets you the children grouped by household and showing the birth order, but you want to cram the children into one row per household (much like my sisters got crammed into one bedroom), so `pivot_wider()` to the rescue:

```
df_children_pivot <- df_children %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = household.ID,
              names_from = birth.order,
              names_glue = "{birth.order}_born",
              values_from = age) %>% 
  print()

# A tibble: 5 × 3
# Groups:   household.ID [5]
  household.ID `1st_born` `2nd_born`
         <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     16523634         19         18
2     16598050         21         NA
3     16611764         28         NA
4     16652356         27         NA
5     16672105         23         13
```

And now, because our cruelty can only go so far, let's take the children that we ripped from their families and stuffed them into single rows, and now we will reunite them with their mothers:

```
df_reunited <- df_mothers %>% 
  left_join(df_children_pivot, by = "household.ID") %>% 
  select(household.ID,Member.ID,birth.year,Gender,age,`1st_born`:last_col()) %>% 
  print()

# A tibble: 7 × 7
  household.ID Member.ID birth.year Gender   age `1st_born` `2nd_born`
         <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     16523634  16529443       1348      2    47         19         18
2     16525912  16529230       1367      2    28         NA         NA
3     16540127  16545263       1319      2    75         NA         NA
4     16611764  16642611       1342      2    52         28         NA
5     16643309  16650210       1336      2    58         NA         NA
6     16652356  16665128       1326      2    68         27         NA
7     16672105  16681528       1352      2    43         23         13
```

Now, I assumed above that the `left_join()` was appropriate and that mothers were present for all children, but I guess it's possible you might have orphans without mothers, so depending on the actual data, it may be necessary for you to adjust what kind of join you use.  But I think this is what you wanted.